# AttributeError: 'ShiftChangeFilter' object has no attribute 'values_list'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-filter

Hello Everyone I am getting Attribute Error. I have one Django based webpage where I am using Django filter to search user result and trying to implement functionality for download filtered result only in order to achieve this I am trying to pass Filter class, in my existing download views. (Earlier my download view is responsible to download all model-based data). My code is

```
from .models import *

import django_filters

class ShiftChangeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = django_filters.NumberFilter(label="DSID")
    class Meta:
        model = ShiftChange
        fields = ['ConnectID', 'EmailID','id','SerialNumber','Project_name','']
```

*My view responsible to download xls file:*

```
from django.utils import timezone
now_aware = timezone.now()
import xlwt,openpyxl
def exportgenesys_data(request):
    allgenesys = ShiftChange.objects.all()
    genesys_filter = ShiftChangeFilter(request.GET,queryset=allgenesys )
    print('download:',genesys_filter.qs)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Genesys_ShiftTiming.xls"'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('GenesysShiftChange Data')  # this will make a sheet named Users Data
    # Sheet header, first row
    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True
    columns = ['id', 'ConnectID', 'Shift_timing', 'EmailID', 'Vendor_Company', 'Project_name', 'SerialNumber',
               'Reason', 'last_updated_time']
    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)  # at 0 row 0 column
    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    rows = genesys_filter.values_list('id', 'ConnectID', 'Shift_timing',
                           'EmailID', 'Vendor_Company', 'Project_name',
                           'SerialNumber', 'Reason', 'last_updated_time')


    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

+Adding Views:

```
def retrieve_view(request):
    allgenesys = ShiftChange.objects.all()
    genesys_filter = ShiftChangeFilter(request.GET, queryset=allgenesys)
    allgenesys = genesys_filter.qs
    print('Retreive:',allgenesys.values_list)
    # print('Genesys Retriew:',allgenesys)

    paginator = Paginator(allgenesys,50)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        allgenesys = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        allgenesys = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        allgenesys = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'apple/shift2.html', {'allgenesys': allgenesys,'genesys_filter':genesys_filter})
```

Comment: It means your ShiftChangeFilter is not have any attribute named values_list

Comment: but values_list is Django ORM right and I have used the same without using a filter and it is not giving any error for downloading all records of model.

Comment: genesys_filter.values_list what is it. this is a Object or any variable

Comment: may be error is comming from there because you cannot assign values_list to a variable i think

Comment: genesys_filter means I'm trying to get the filtered model object and then value_list means which fields I want inside it.
print('download:',genesys_filter.qs) => Problem here at this line I have checked it is giving me all model object whereas my render views.py giving me correct filtered object.i.e print('Retreive:',allgenesys.values_list) Please check updated views.py